# How do I count the length and width of each lead? (Python OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, blob, contour

[image: The image of chip that I'm using to process]

I'm using python OpenCV. I'm pretty new to python and OpenCV. My task is to count the length and width of each lead, and the distance between each lead. Basically my code thresholds the photo and removes all those small dust and noise. However, I do not know how to manipulate findContours() method to draw a minimum rectangle on the lead so that I can calculate the length and width.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import random as rng
rng.seed(12345)


def thresh_callback(val):
    threshold = val

    canny_output = cv2.Canny(slicedImage, threshold, threshold * 2)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(canny_output, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    contours_poly = [None] * len(contours)
    boundRect = [None] * len(contours)
    centers = [None] * len(contours)
    radius = [None] * len(contours)
    for i, c in enumerate(contours):
        contours_poly[i] = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)
        boundRect[i] = cv2.boundingRect(contours_poly[i])
        centers[i], radius[i] = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i])

    drawing = np.zeros((canny_output.shape[0], canny_output.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    for i in range(len(contours)):
        color = (rng.randint(0, 256), rng.randint(0, 256), rng.randint(0, 256))
        cv2.drawContours(drawing, contours_poly, i, color)
        cv2.rectangle(drawing, (int(boundRect[i][0]), int(boundRect[i][1])), \
                     (int(boundRect[i][0] + boundRect[i][2]), int(boundRect[i][1] + boundRect[i][3])), color, 2)
        cv2.circle(drawing, (int(centers[i][0]), int(centers[i][1])), int(radius[i]), color, 2)

    cv2.imshow('Contours', drawing)

img = cv2.imread('photo1.png', 0)
x1 = 260
x2 = 1180
y1 = 340
y2 = 1270
slicedImage = img[y1:y2, x1:x2]
slicedImage = cv2.medianBlur(slicedImage, 7)
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(slicedImage, 155, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find image contours
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Maximum blob size
max_threshold_blob_area = 100



# Loop over all contours and fill draw white colour for area smaller than threshold
for i in range(1, len(contours)):
    index_level = int(hierarchy[0][i][1])
    if index_level <= i:
        cnt = contours[i]
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        print(area)
        if area <= max_threshold_blob_area:
            # Draw white colour for small blobs
            cv2.drawContours(thresh1, [cnt], -1, 0, -1, 1)

canny_output = cv2.Canny(thresh1, 100, 200)

cv2.imshow("Result", thresh1)
cv2.waitKey(0)

source_window = 'Source'
cv2.namedWindow(source_window)
cv2.imshow(source_window, thresh1)
max_thresh = 255
thresh = 100 # initial threshold
cv2.createTrackbar('Canny thresh:', source_window, thresh, max_thresh, thresh_callback)
thresh_callback(thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```